# Permanently delete using delete key - Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I set the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to do the same thing as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>: permanently delete files, rather than sending them to the trash can?

I'm using Linux Mint 14, a Debian distro, with the Cinnamon desktop and Nemo file manager (based on Nautilus).

Comment: Use `rm` command to delete file permanently.

Comment: I'm asking about deleting within a file manager, not at the command-line.

Comment: When I pressed shift+delete in **Nautilus** File manager, File will be deleted permanently.

Comment: Yes, that also works in Nemo, which is based on Nautilus.  My question is, how can I do the same thing by pressing just the delete key?